# Mac file download behaviour

Tags: macos, data-transfer

Is there a way to prevent files being downloaded into the Downloads folder on a Mac such as when I open a PDF file from the browser instead of downloading it?

To explain what I mean, on Windows when you click 'Open' when the browser asks what to do with a file, the file gets downloaded to a temp folder.

On Mac it gets downloaded to the Downloads folder, in effect creating two copies if I choose to save the file later to a different folder. Since you can't move files on the Mac, the end result is a very cluttered Downloads folder and no way of knowing if a certain file is saved elsewhere?

Is there a way to change this behaviour, say not to have the file downloaded or to have it automatically deleted?

Comment: We seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding here... what makes you think you can't move a file? Also, you realise you don't actually have to 'Open' an online pdf to read it, you can read it right there in the browser [with it being downloaded to a temporary area & deleted later as the cache expires]

Comment: @Tetsujin To move a file in mac, i have to copy it to the new location and then delete it from the original location, correct me if I am wrong. To me this is rather inefficient. I could read on the browser, but since I work on a small screen and because sometimes equations don't render correctly in a browser, I like to read on a real pdf program. And partly it is just an old habit.

Comment: @Arun You could drag and drop it in the new location, or Cmd+C to copy, then Cmd+Option+V to move it to the new location instead of making a new copy of the file.

Comment: If you move a file **on the same partition** it simply moves to the new location. If you move it **to another partition** it will copy [same as any OS would]. If you hold Cmd whilst dragging, it will move instead. ...If you want to move using only key commands, then you Cmd/C to copy [Cmd/V of course to Paste] **or** Cmd/Opt/V to Move.

Answer (score 1):

**Just right click the link.**

[image]

If you have a pdf viewer plugin enabled (which it sounds like you do), you have the option to *Open Link in..." it or *Save Link As...*

When you choose *Save Link As...* you even have the opportunity to change your download location.

[image]

The way that I am doing is through **Full Acrobat Reader**, not through a 3rd party plugin or Preview.  In fact, PDF plugin is disabled:

[image]

When I click on the PDF link, it opens in a new browser Tab for viewing, but now I have the opportunity to select "Download" if I want to save it (It's not saved to my Downloads folder automatically.)

[image]

Comment: I know this, I want a way to view the document in a pdf viewer before saving it.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. Maybe I should just use the inbuilt viewer instead of the system viewer. I just prefer to read pdfs on a larger window.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Preview is great for graphics, but PDFs - I swear by the genuine Adobe Acrobat client.